# Curvatres specialized on disc

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Consider an open disk of unit radius in the real (two dimensional) plane.If we want to define the Ricci curvature and bisectional curvature on that disc,what will be their equivalent forms and the significance?Also if our disc is considered to be in the complex one dimensional plane what will be the Holomorphic bisectional curvature?
I have just started learning differential geometry.I'm trying to relate the higher dimensional concepts to the lower dimensional concepts.

Comment: To define any of those curvatures, you need to specify a Riemannian metric. Which one are you using?

Comment: The Euclidean metric seems to be easier.Can the usual definition that is "A smooth symmetric covariant 2-tensor field on the disc" be specialized?

Comment: There is also the hyperbolic metric on the disc which has different curvatures than the Euclidean metric.